# Unable to create deployment in a namespace with service account, ClusterRole and ClusterRolebinding created

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-security

I was getting my hands dirty practicing the Security k8s. This was a practice question I came across to solve.
**Question:**
Create `serviceaccount` 'john' with permissions to create delete get deployments, statefulsets, daemonsets in a given `namespace 'hr'` Create `clusterrole and clusterrolebindings` required.

**Approach:**
Have tried creating sa and clusterrole and clusterrolebinding (binded the clusterrole with the sa created)
But when I checked it is giving a 'no'

```
kubectl auth can-i create deploy --as john -n hr

no
```

To create sa:

```
kubectl create sa john
```

To create clusterrole:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  # "namespace" omitted since ClusterRoles are not namespaced
  name: hrcrole
rules:
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  #
  # at the HTTP level, the name of the resource for accessing Secret
  # objects is "secrets"
  resources: ["deployments", "statefulsets", "daemonsets"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "delete"]
```

To create clusterrolebinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
# This cluster role binding allows anyone in the "manager" group to read secrets in any namespace.
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: hrcrolebind
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: hruser # Name is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: hrcrole
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

I have also tried creating serviceaccount in the namespace, creating clusterrolebinding in namespace but still I get no. Unfortunately I don't have a solution for this problem. Appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to `create` a deployment:

```
kubectl auth can-i create deploy --as john -n hr
```

But you don't have the `create` verb allowed in the cluster role:

```
verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "delete"]
```

Try recreating the cluster role like this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  # "namespace" omitted since ClusterRoles are not namespaced
  name: hrcrole
rules:
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  #
  # at the HTTP level, the name of the resource for accessing Secret
  # objects is "secrets"
  resources: ["deployments", "statefulsets", "daemonsets"]
  verbs: ["create", "get", "watch", "list", "delete"]
```

Comment: I overlooked that one. thanks for pointing it out.